# Fibonacci Sequence Error C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, sequence, fibonacci

I have an assignment where i have to write fibonacci's sequence and then print the first n numbers of it, where n is input by the user. What i wrote is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

int n, i, seq[n];
scanf("%d", &n);
seq[0]=0; seq[1]=1;
for(i=2; i<n; i++)
seq[i]=seq[i-1]+seq[i-2];

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
printf("%d ", seq[i]);
return(0);
}
```

Which works until n is equal or bigger than nine. Supposing that you input 8, the sequence will be 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 as it should be. If you input 9 or bigger the sequence looks like this 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 -9 (bunch of random numbers).

Anyone who can point out the problem? Thx in advance.

Comment: Use indentation. Use  braces. Check return value from `scanf`

Comment: Is the code psychic on knowing the value for `n` when doing `seq[n]`

Answer (score 4):

You declare `int n, i, seq[n];` before you have a value of `n` to set the array's length with.  The behavior for an uninitialized variable is undefined.

You don't need an array to do this assignment as described.  You just need to remember the last and current Fibonacci values.  Sum them to produce the new one, then migrate current -> last and new -> current.  Put that logic in a loop controlled by `n`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Was able to resolve the problem also using arrays

Comment: Yes, you can do it by creating your array after you get the value of `n`.  However, given two correct solutions that both work in linear time, why would you want the solution that requires more resources?

Answer (score 2):

`seq[n]` is a variable-length array with the size `n`, which is **uninitialized** at that point, leading to undefined behavior.

Instead invoke `scanf` **first** to move some value to `n`, **then** define `int seq[n]`:

```
int n, i;
scanf("%d", &n);
int seq[n];
```

You can also use `malloc`:

```
int n, i;
assert(1 == scanf("%d", &n));
int* seq = malloc(n * sizeof(*seq));
```

Don't forget to call `free` afterwards, though!

Comment: thx for the idea but i'm not allowed to use the malloc function yet. I'm at the start of my c language class and we're barely past for statements

Comment: @DavideCocomazzi You can still use the variable-length array, then, as described in my answer...